# FactoryGirl won't create nested objects without reloading parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to use `rspec` and `FactoryGirl` for my acceptance tests in Rails app.

I have `Program`, `ProgramLesson`, `Course`, `Lesson` objects.

Here are the models:

```
class Program < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :program_lessons
  has_many :courses
end

class ProgramLesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lessons
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :program
  has_many :lessons
end

class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :program_lesson
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Here are factories for those things:

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :program do
        after(:create) do |object|
          create_list(:program_lesson, 10, program: object)
          create(:course, program: object)
        end
    end

    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :course do
        program
        after(:create) { |object| object.program.program_lessons.each { |pl| create(:lesson, course: object, program_lesson: 
      end    
    end
```

So, factories are creating `program`, then `program_lessons` for that `program`, then `course` that belongs_to `program`, and then `course.lessons` which belong to `course` and to `program_lesson`.

The problem is that `course.lessons` will only be created when I use `byebug` and `program.reload` before creating them. Why is this happening?

Comment: Is `ProgramLesson` a join model in a `has_many through:` association? In that case you don't need to create it manually. Just create the lessons from the association and rails will handle it for you. In FactoryGirl you would use `create_list(:lesson, 10, course: object)`

Comment: But I would really use [traits](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#traits) for this as instead of making your regular factories slow.

Comment: No, it's not. Thanks, @max

Comment: Then you might want to include the models in the question.

Comment: @max added models

Comment: I think the problem is actually how you have defined your associations in your models - not the factories. You should be setting up [indirect assocations with the `through:` option](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-associationl).  I'm still really confused about what role ProgramLesson is supposed to play if you are not using it as a many to 
 many join between Program and Lesson. (A lesson can belong to many programs)